# NavigationView.PaneDisplayMode changes the UI only after resizing the application window

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have a simple test application with a MainPage.xaml as follows:

```
<NavigationView x:Name="MainPageNavigationView"
                Style="{StaticResource MainPageNavigationViewStyle}"
                ItemInvoked="MainPageNavigationView_ItemInvoked"
                Loaded="MainPageNavigationView_Loaded">

    <NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItem Icon="Home" Tag="Home_Page">
            <TextBlock Tag="Home_Page">Home</TextBlock>
        </NavigationViewItem>
    </NavigationView.MenuItems>

</NavigationView>
```

In the Resource Dictionary I have defined NavigationViews Style as follows:

```
<Style TargetType="NavigationView" x:Key="MainPageNavigationViewStyle">
    <Setter Property="IsBackButtonVisible" Value="Collapsed" />
    <Setter Property="PaneDisplayMode" Value="LeftCompact" />
    <Setter Property="IsSettingsVisible" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="IsBackEnabled" Value="False" />
</Style>
```

My problem is that when I start the application either in debug mode from Visual Studio, or deploy it to my machine and run it, the PaneDisplayMode setting kicks in only after I have resized the window by any amount. But as I understand it the application should start with the NavigationView already in the configured state.

Is there something obvious that I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `NavigationView` to be closed when it is loaded, you can set `IsPaneOpen` to `False` in the `<Style>`.

```xml
<Style TargetType="NavigationView" x:Key="MainPageNavigationViewStyle">
    ...
    <Setter Property="IsPaneOpen" Value="False"/>
    ...
</Style>
```

Best regards.